# xFinium Pdf: ConvertPdfToImage create nullpointerexception

Tags: android, image, pdf, xamarin

I am using xFinium to generate image from Pdf Document. I have tried few of the pdf that get rendered and converted to image but there is one pdf file which contains 1 page of musical piece which get a null pointer exception.

Not sure what is the problem:

[image]

Comment: I work for the company that develops XFINIUM.PDF library. Please send the PDF file to our support or post a link to the file here and we'll investigate it.

Comment: Do you have their email address?

Comment: support@xfiniumpdf.com